# Treasure of the fancy island

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

The colored rectangle below is the map of a fancy island. There is a treasure hidden there, but instead of the usual X on the map to depict the location of the treasure you have the following clues instead:

**1.** The square of the treasure does not have a yellow neighbor.

**2.** The square of the treasure and its symmetric about the center of the rectangle have different colors.

**3.** The square of the treasure has a neighbor with the same color as itself.

**4.** The square of the treasure is unique in its column.

(A neighbor square is one that is adjacent horizontally, vertically or diagonally.)

[image]

I attach the image using numbers for the colorblind (yellow is 4).

[image]

Find the square of the treasure!

Comment: Yes, it does, @BeastlyGerbil, as it is mentioned.

Comment: Can you clarify no. 2? I don't understand what you mean

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil most likely http://www.metafysica.nl/turing/symm_center.jpg

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Exactly. For example the green in the first column and the bottom light blue of the last column are symmetric about the center of the rectangle.

Comment: @Alexandros9 ah ok thanks I see now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

one with black cross

> [image]
>
>  1. does not have a yellow neighbor
>  2. symmetric is green one
>  3. it has neighbor with the same color
>  4. and it is unique in column
>
>  My strategy: Elimination (obviously?)

Comment: I think the "neighbor" thing designate squares directly to the bottom, left, top or right, not in the top-left, top-right, bottom-left or bottom-right. But instead of having to do it over, you can just deduce from your previous work that the treasure would be in one of the squares in a corner of a yellow square.

Comment: @DorianFusco: From the question: "A neighbor square is one that is adjacent horizontally, vertically or diagonally."

Comment: Oh, my bad, I didn't read the paranthesis ! In the meantime, I looked at the diagonal neighbors of the yellow squares and the question would have no answers otherwise ^^'

Comment: Thanks for the solution Jan Ivan. Just a comment: There are many ways to start the elimination. It seems that starting with either clue 1 or clue 4 is the fastest.